# PhpStorm | Get rid of the "edit rectangles"

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, emmet

When I use snippets in PhpStorm, especially Emmet features, I often get constructions with several highlighted edit point. I can jump over them with <kbd>Tab</kbd> in case to edit the "key places" of the construction.

[image: Here is the example screen.]

This might be a great feature, but if talking about Emmet, it causes some problems. After typing `div*5` I want to [enter] inside the first `div` but the cursor just moves down to the next edit rectangle. The only solution I know is to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to remove all active edit points which is quite inconvenient.

[image: Example.]

Is it possible to disable those edit points especially for Emmet or for the whole IDE?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot disable them. You can visually hide them (by changing their colors); you may prevent showing not active segments (via hidden settings) .. but there is no known to me option to disable them (except pressing `Esc`). And my quick searches showed no matching tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%22live%20template%20variable%22

Comment: *"I want to [enter] inside the first div but the cursor just moves down to the next edit rectangle"* You may remove `Enter` shortcut from that action and leave only `Tab` there: "Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Keymap | All Actions | Editor Actions | Next Template Variable..." (tip: you can use a special button there and search actions by assigned shortcuts as well)

Comment: Thank you very much! Didnt expect my first question here to be answered so quickly :)